# Изменение свойства нескольких одинаковых объектов

Tags: winforms, powershell

Есть ряд одинаковых объектов Windows.Forms, по которым нужно пробежаться и заполнить элементами некоторого массива. Как я написал сейчас и как не работает :

```
$DNSTextBoxes = ("DNSTextBox1","DNSTextBox2","DNSTextBox3","DNSTextBox4")
for($i = 0; $i -lt $DNSTextBoxes.Length;$i++)
{
      $DNSTextBoxes[$i].Text = $array[$i]
}
```

При запуске появляется следующая ошибка : The property 'Text' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
Пробовал иначе, ошибка та же:

```
$DNSTextBoxes = ("DNSTextBox1","DNSTextBox2","DNSTextBox3","DNSTextBox4")
$i=0       
ForEach($TextBox in $DNSTextBoxes)
{
      $TextBox.Text = $array[$i]
      $i++
}
```

Comment: `"DNSTextBox1"` - это строковый литерал, т. к. в кавычках. Соответственно, в `$DNSTextBoxes` содержатся просто строки. А должны быть ссылки на компоненты-текстбоксы.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Спасибо, почему-то сам не догадался, заработало. А существует ли способ пройтись по компонентам DNSTextBox каким-нибудь циклом, вместо номера подставляя $i? А не храня элементы в массиве, как в моем примере

Comment: Все контролы хранятся в коллекции `Controls` родительского компонента. Вот по этой коллекции и нужно проходить. Если там есть и другие контролы, то отфильтровать нужные с помощью линковского метода `OfType<TextBox>()`.

Comment: Ещё есть метод [Find](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov как я понял, OfType<T>() мне не особо подходит, потому что объектов типа TextBox у меня довольно много. Решил попробовать    Control.ControlCollection.Find , но не понял как мне с ним работать, написал так:
    $DNSTextBoxes = $NetworkForm.Controls.Find("DNSTextBox", true)
(нормального this в PowerShell нет, указывал явно название формы) и получил следующее: Unexpected token 'true' in expression or statement. Написал так:
    $NetworkForm.Controls.Find("DNSTextBox", true)
и вот что: Cannot find an overload for "Find" and the argument count: "1"

Comment: В powershell булевы значения заданы константами `$true` и `$false`.

Comment: Чтобы было легко обращаться к нужным контролам, следует группировать их. Например, все текстбоксы, в которые вводятся DNS, нужно поместить на отдельную панель (контрол типа Panel или GroupBox). После чего с ними легко работать, т. к. они все в одной коллекции DNSpanel.Controls.